# How do I convert a JSON object into a dictionary with Path being the key

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Using Newtonsoft.Json how do I convert a JSON object into a dictionary with Path being the key?

```
IDictionary<string, object> FlattenJson(string Json)
{
  JToken Input = JToken.Parse(Json);

  ... magic ...

  return Result;
}
```

Key of the dictionary shall be the JToken.Path value and Value of the dictionary shall be the actual value in its "native" format (string as string, integer a long, etc).

"message.body.titles[0].formats[0].images[0].uri" => "I/41SKCXdML._SX160_SY120_.jpg"
"message.body.titles[0].formats[0].images[0].widthPx" => 0
"message.body.titles[0].customerReviewsCollectionIncluded" => False
...

Is there anything out-of-the-box that works for arbitrary JSON?

Comment: I don't think there is anything out of the box that does this. Are you sure the JToken.Path is unique so that you can use it as a key?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# flattening json structure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394551/c-sharp-flattening-json-structure)

Comment: @Jacob - I don't think this is a duplicate.  That answer won't handle arrays, and uses a somewhat different scheme for defining the key text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to recursively traverse the Json.NET hierarchy, pick out the primitive values (which have type [`JValue`](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JValue.htm)), and store their values in the dictionary, like so:

```
public static class JsonExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<JToken> WalkTokens(this JToken node)
    {
        if (node == null)
            yield break;
        yield return node;
        foreach (var child in node.Children())
            foreach (var childNode in child.WalkTokens())
                yield return childNode;
    }

    public static IDictionary<string, object> ToValueDictionary(this JToken root)
    {
        return root.WalkTokens().OfType<JValue>().ToDictionary(value => value.Path, value => value.Value);
    }
}
```

And then call it like

```
var Result = Input.ToValueDictionary();
```

Note that integers will be stored as `Int64`.