# How to add a new JProperty to a JSON based on path?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

There is a large JSON file (about a thousand lines). The task is to update existing JProperties, or add new JProperties in a specific location in the structure. The location of the new texts are based on the JToken.Path property. For example, this is the start of the JSON:

```cs
"JonSnow": {
    "Direwolf": {
        "Name": "Ghost",
        "Color": "White",
    }
}
"DanaerysTargaryen": {
    "Dragons": {
        "Dragon1": {
            "Name": "Drogon",
        }
    }
    "Hair": {
        "Color": "White"
    }
}
```

Now the JSON must be updated using a given list of JToken paths and the corresponding values.

The first possibility is, the JProperty corresponding to the path might already exist, in which case the value needs to be updated. I am already successfully implementing this with `JToken.Replace()`.

The second possibility is, the JProperty does not exist yet and needs to be added. For example, I need to add `"DanaerysTargaryen.Dragons.Dragon1.Color"` with the value `"Black"`.

I know I can use the JSON.Net `Add()` method, but to use this only the final child token of the path can be missing from the JSON. For example, I can use

```cs
JObject ObjToUpdate= JObject.Parse(jsonText);
JObject Dragon = ObjToUpdate["DanaerysTargaryen"]["Dragons"]["Dragon1"] as JObject;
Dragon.Add("Color", "Black"));
```

But what about if I need to add `"JonSnow.Weapon.Type"` with the value `"Longsword"`? Because `"Weapon"` does not exist yet as a JProperty, and it needs to be added along with `"Type" : "Longsword"`. With each path, it is **unknown** how much of the path already exists in the JSON. How can this be parameterised?

```cs
// from outside source: Dictionary<string, string> PathBasedDict 
// key: Jtoken.Path (example: "JonSnow.Weapon.Type")
// value: new text to be added (example: "Longsword")

foreach(KeyValuePair entry in PathBasedDict)
{
    string path = entry.Key;
    string newText = entry.Value;

    if (ObjToUpdate.SelectToken(path) != null)  
        { ObjToUpdate.SelectToken(path).Replace(newText); }

    else AddToJson(path, newText);
}
```

What should `AddToJson()` look like? Iterating through the entire path and checking each possible JProperty to see if it exists, and then adding the rest underneath, seems very cumbersome. Is there a better way to do this? Any Json.NET tricks I am unaware of? I am not even sure how the iteration could be parameterised.

Comment: You could just split your path by `"."`, then `foreach` over that, adding or retrieving the `JToken` as you go...

Comment: Heretic Monkey, thanks for the tip. But to add the JToken, I also have to add the other JProperties which it contains, that the `foreach` has not reached yet. Am I understanding this wrongly?

Comment: Another option is to create your data object from the JSON using an [ExpandoObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.expandoobject) (from System.Dynamic) and build/modify your object(s) at run-time, add or remove properties if/when required, then serialize the new JSON. See also [Walkthrough: Creating and Using Dynamic Objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/walkthrough-creating-and-using-dynamic-objects)

Comment: Related or duplicate: [How to unflatten flattened json in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40541842/3744182).  The accepted answer there populates arrays as well as objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few ways of going about this. Here are two of them.

1. To go along with your existing code, split the path by `'.'`, then iterate over them. If the path is not there, create it with `Add`. Otherwise, if we're on the last part of the path, just add the value.

   ```
   var json = JObject.Parse(@"{""DanaerysTargaryen"":{""Dragons"":{""Dragon1"":{""Name"": ""Drogon""}},""Hair"": {""Color"": ""White""}}}");
   var toAdd = "DanaerysTargaryen.Dragons.Dragon1.Color";
   var valueToAdd = "Black";
   var pathParts = toAdd.Split('.');
   JToken node = json;
   for (int i = 0; i < pathParts.Length; i++)
   {
       var pathPart = pathParts[i];
       var partNode = node.SelectToken(pathPart);
       if (partNode == null && i < pathParts.Length - 1)
       {
           ((JObject)node).Add(pathPart, new JObject());
           partNode = node.SelectToken(pathPart);
       }
       else if (partNode == null && i == pathParts.Length - 1)
       {
           ((JObject)node).Add(pathPart, valueToAdd);
           partNode = node.SelectToken(pathPart);
       }
       node = partNode;
   }

   Console.WriteLine(json.ToString());
   ```

[(Example on dotnetfiddle.net)](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0sXKJU)

2. Otherwise, you could create a separate `JObject` that represents the node(s) you want to add, then merge them.

   ```
    var json = JObject.Parse(@"{""DanaerysTargaryen"":{""Dragons"":{""Dragon1"":{""Name"": ""Drogon""}},""Hair"": {""Color"": ""White""}}}");
    var toMerge = @"{""DanaerysTargaryen"":{""Dragons"":{""Dragon1"":{""Color"":""Black""}}}}";
    var jsonToMerge = JObject.Parse(toMerge);
    json.Merge(jsonToMerge);
    Console.WriteLine(json.ToString());
   ```

[(Example on dotnetfiddle.net)](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DqpdqZ)

Comment: In first approach, It is dangerous to determine last path part based on string equality. Foreach should be replaced with for loop.

Comment: "It is dangerous"... what's the danger? "Foreach should be replaced with for loop." Why? I'm fine with criticism, but I take it more seriously when backed up with facts and citations, not just assertions.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough, the code do not handle path with repeating part paths, such as "foo.bar.foo.bar", it could jump to incorrect if/elseif statement due to string comparsion of part path, thats why I advised that e.g. for loop with index comaprsion should be done.

Comment: Oh, I see, yes, this code was specific to the OP's situation, but I see how it would fail in the general case. Thanks! Edited.

Answer (score 7):

Based on first approach from [Heretic Monkey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56429860/1218508), here is an extension method:

```cs
public static class JObjectExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Replaces value based on path. New object tokens are created for missing parts of the given path.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="self">Instance to update</param>
    /// <param name="path">Dot delimited path of the new value. E.g. 'foo.bar'</param>
    /// <param name="value">Value to set.</param>
    public static void ReplaceNested(this JObject self, string path, JToken value)
    {
        if (self is null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(self));
        
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
            throw new ArgumentException("Path cannot be null or empty", nameof(path));

        var pathParts = path.Split('.');
        JToken currentNode = self;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < pathParts.Length; i++)
        {
            var pathPart = pathParts[i];
            var isLast = i == pathParts.Length - 1;
            var partNode = currentNode.SelectToken(pathPart);
            
            if (partNode is null)
            {
                var nodeToAdd = isLast ? value : new JObject();
                ((JObject)currentNode).Add(pathPart, nodeToAdd);
                currentNode = currentNode.SelectToken(pathPart);
            }
            else
            {
                currentNode = partNode;

                if (isLast)
                    currentNode.Replace(value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```