# How do I convert a dictionary representing a flattened object back into a C# object or json object?

Tags: c#

My requirement is the reverse of the following question: [C# flattening json structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394551/c-sharp-flattening-json-structure)

If I've a dictionary that represents flattened paths and values of an object, I need to construct a Json Object based on those keys and values.

Example:

```
var flatObjDict = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    { "name", "test" },
    { "father/name", "Mike" },
    { "father/age", 70 },
    { "father/dog/color", "Red" }
}
```

I need a function that can take above dictionary as input and return following object:

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "father": {
         "name": "Mike"
         "age": 70,
         "dog": {
             "color": "Red"
         }
    }
}
```

The `/` separator can be present any number of times in the dictionary keys.

Comment: There is nothing built-in to Json.NET or Systm.Text.Json to do this, you will have to write it yourself.

Comment: You are encouraged to make an attempt to write your code.  If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that.  Please provide specific information about that attempt and what didn't work as expected.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: You might check whether [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40858665) by [Danny Su](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1311686/danny-su) to [How to unflatten flattened json in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40541842) can be adapted to do what you want.  You would need to adapt `SplitPath(string path)` to account for the fact that you are using a `/` as your separator character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a toy solution.

```csharp
public static string Unflatten(Dictionary<string, object> flattened)
{
    IDictionary<string, object> root = new ExpandoObject();
    foreach (var entry in flattened)
    {
        var path = entry.Key.Split("/");
        var target = root;
        foreach (var segment in path.SkipLast(1))
        {
            if (!target.ContainsKey(segment))
            {
                target[segment] = new ExpandoObject();
            }
            target = (IDictionary<string, object>)target[segment];
        }

        target[path.Last()] = entry.Value;
    }
    return JsonSerializer.Serialize(root, new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true });
}
```

It doesn't have any features beyond what was described, so arrays etc. are not considered.

Here's a fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/B5Z8HD